# How to list view tables in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw, catalog

I am required to list down all the tables created by view. I know SYSIBM.SYSTABLES will list down all tables, but which field in SYSIBM.SYSTABLES is used to identify that the table is created using view?

Note: I am using DB2 V10.5.

Edit: Reply to @mustaccio, below is the sample of view table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (
    ...
) AS (
    ...
);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "table is created using view"? May be provide an example? Both tables and views will be present in `syscat.tables`, where the value in the `type` column would distinguish between tables and views ('T' and 'V' respectively).

Comment: @mustaccio, thanks. The column "type" is what I need. I edited the post to put an example to create view table.

Answer (score 3):

Db2 provides [documented catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html). The one for tables is [SYSCAT.TABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html). If the **TYPE** column has a value **V**, then it is a **view**.

```
select tabname,tabschema from syscat.tables
where type='V'
```